# Modificar ruta al publicar aplicación ASP.NET(C#) en servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Tengo una aplicación la cual desarrolle en ASP.NET(C#) la cual trabaja con la librería ItexSharp, el cual realiza un documento en PDF sobre un cuestionario. Al correr la aplicacion dentro de Visual Studio corre sin problemas ya que dentro de la codificacion del PDF utilice imagenes que solo pude declara asi:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(" C:/Users/MVALDERRAMA/source/repos/ExamenWEBKarossoV2/ExamenWEBKarosso/tablaCali.png");
            imagen2.BorderWidth = 0;
            imagen2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            percentage = 300 / imagen2.Width;
            imagen2.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
            imagen2.SetAbsolutePosition(130, 20);
            document.Add(imagen2);
```

**Mi duda es:**
Como puedo hacer para al momento de publicarlo en un servidor obviamente ya no tomara la imagen de esa ruta, como puedo hacer para que tome la ruta donde este la carpeta de los archivos del proyecto o solamente tiene que ser manual todo por ejemplo:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ExamenKarosso/karosso.jpg");
            imagen.BorderWidth = 0;
            imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            float percentage = 0.0f;
            percentage = 100 / imagen.Width;
            imagen.ScalePercent(percentage * 50);
            imagen.SetAbsolutePosition(10, 800);
            document.Add(imagen);
```

Gracias, espero haberme explicado de la mejor manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener la carpeta de ejecucion del programa utilizando [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx). Esto te **retornara la ruta de la carpeta `bin` donde esta publicado tu programa** y luego solo tendrás que agregarle el nombre del archivo al final:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "karosso.jpg"));
//..
```

Si tu carpeta no esta dentro de la carpeta bin, sino un directorio mas arriba, entonces utiliza `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` con la expresion `..\` para navegar un folder arriba:

```
var rootDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\")
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.IO.Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "karosso.jpg"));
```

Comment: !!MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS!!. Justo lo que necesitaba.